# How to overcome Type error with subprocess call python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

The below script was running fine with python2.7 while with python3 its giving error, this is just basically to check the disk file-system space check.

can not recall how to correct , any help will be much appreciated.

**Script:**

```
import subprocess
import socket
threshold = 10
hst_name = (socket.gethostname())

def fs_function(usage):
   return_val = None
   try:
      return_val = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-Ph', usage], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   except IndexError:
      print("Mount point not found.")
   return return_val


def show_result(output, mount_name):
   if len(output) > 0:
      for x in output[1:]:
          perc = int(x.split()[-2][:-1])
          if perc >= threshold:
            print("Service Status:  Filesystem For " + mount_name + " is not normal and " + str(perc) + "% used on the host",hst_name)
          else:
            print("Service Status:  Filesystem For " + mount_name + " is normal on the host",hst_name)
def fs_main():
   rootfs = fs_function("/")
   varfs  = fs_function("/var")
   tmPfs = fs_function("/tmp")

   output = rootfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
   show_result(output, "root (/)")

   output = varfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
   show_result(output, "Var (/var)")

   output = tmPfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
   show_result(output, "tmp (/tmp)")
fs_main()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fsusaage.py", line 42, in <module>
    fs_main()
  File "./fsusaage.py", line 34, in fs_main
    output = rootfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to split the `stdout.PIPE` from the subprocess—a bytes object—using a regular string.

You can either convert the output to a regular string before splitting it (probably what you want):

```py
output = str(rootfs.communicate()[0]).strip().split('\n')
```

or you can split it using a bytes object:

```py
output = rootfs.communicate()[0].strip().split(b'\n')
```

Note: you will need to do the same for `varfs` and `tmPfs`.